# Why cant commit changes during scheduled method?

Tags: java, spring, transactional, spring-scheduled

I have problem to save updated object to DB during `@Scheduled` method. In old posts I've found that I need to split `@Scheduled` and `@Transactional` method to two different classes, but no changes. Is there any different way or did I make something wrong ?

Create Test interface also did not helped

Class with `@Scheduled`

```
@Service
@EnableScheduling
public class CronNotification {

@Autowired
private SentNotificationDao sentNotificationDao;

@Autowired
private Test Test;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
public void delay() {
    List<SentNotification> sentNotificationList = sentNotificationDao.findByIdGreaterThan(26); 
    for (SentNotification sentNotification : sentNotificationList) {
        sentNotification.setUserResponse(true);
        //sentNotificationDao.save(sentNotification);
        Test.rob(sentNotification);
    }
}
```

Next class with `@Transactional`

```
@Service
public class Test {

@Autowired
private SentNotificationDao sentNotificationDao;

@Transactional
public void rob(SentNotification sentNotification) {
    sentNotificationDao.save(sentNotification);
}
```

}

Comment: Only adding `@Transactional` will do nothing, not without `@EnableTransactionManagement` and a proper tx configuration. Also those `@Enable*` annotations should really go on `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: @EnableTransactionManagement is placed in config file. I'm not sure about tx configuration, but rest of the communication with database is working fine.